# Ubuntu 16.04 requiring manual interaction to become 'active' after reboot?

Tags: ssh, reboot

I have an old laptop that I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on, and I have tried to set it up so that I can use remotely through ssh (just playing around really - I am fairly new to Linux in general). All is well, except for the fact that when I `sudo reboot`, the machine *will* reboot but it won't become 'active' (for lack of a better word, I guess - it is running, but won't connect to WiFi or run any startup scripts) until a mouse is moved or a keyboard button is pressed - and I obviously don't want to do this everytime I reboot. This might have something to do with the lid remaining closed, but not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Edit systemd's configuration file using:

```
gksu gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Look for and change this line to look like:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

HTH

Comment: Setting `HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore` didn't do anything, but setting `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` did. Not quite sure what docked means in this instance - have a HDMI cable and AC adapter plugged in.